# Right-align last submenu of a css drop-down menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, alignment

Would like the last submenu of this css drop-down menu to be right-aligned: https://jsfiddle.net/mishka00/p6cyy5p7/. It is currently right-aligned (incorrectly) just to show the desired end result. Tried various combinations of `right:0` and `left:auto`, but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add `position: relative` for `#nav ul li`
2. add `right: 0;` for `#nav ul li:last-child ul`

```css
#nav ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
}
#nav ul li {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    margin:0 30px;
    position: relative;
}
#nav ul li a {
    display:block;
    padding:10px 6px;
    position:relative;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
    border-left:1px solid #E9E9E9;
    border-right:1px solid #E9E9E9;
    border-top:1px solid #E9E9E9;
}
#nav ul li ul {
    display:none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    background:#fff;
    width:150px;
    border:0;
}
#nav ul li ul li {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    border:none;
    float:none;
    margin:0;
    left:-1px;
}
#nav ul li ul li:hover {
    border:none;
    background:#F7F9FB;
}
#nav ul li ul li a {
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #E9E9E9;
}
#nav ul li:last-child ul {    
    right: 0;
    background:white;
}
#nav ul li:last-child ul li{
    left:1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu1</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="menu.html">Item1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="menu.html">Item2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="menu.html">Item3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="menu.html">Item4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu2</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="menu.html">Item1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="menu.html">Item2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="menu.html">Item3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="menu.html">Item4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu3</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="menu.html">Item1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="menu.html">Item2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="menu.html">Item3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="menu.html">Item4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div style='clear: both;margin-bottom:5px;'></div>
<div style='border-top:1px solid navy;'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

See https://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/b1pyqLpc/

```
#nav ul li:last-child ul {
  right:0px;left:auto;
  text-align:right;
  background:white;
}
```

Plus add position:relative to the parent

Answer (score 0):

just add this code to your css

```
#nav ul li:last-of-type {
    float: right;
}
```