# How to right align a CSS dropdown to its parent div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, dropdown, right-align

I want to create a dropdown that right aligns itself to its parent element

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4vVd.png), but where the dropdown's right edge is aligned to its parent's right edge

[This](https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-dropdown-menus/) link contains the styling I want, the alignment is just not working properly. Any help would be very much appreciated!

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  font-family: monospace;
}

ul {
  background: darkorange;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  color: #fff;
  background: darkorange;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

li a {
  color: #fff;
}

li:hover {
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li ul {
  background: orange;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  min-width: 5rem;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover>ul,
ul li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283473/right-align-last-submenu-of-a-css-drop-down-menu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Right-align last submenu of a css drop-down menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283473/right-align-last-submenu-of-a-css-drop-down-menu)

Answer (score -1):

Convert `left: 0` to `right: 0` and change some CSS properties can right-align your dropdown

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  font-family: monospace;
}

ul {
  background: darkorange;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  color: #fff;
  background: darkorange;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

li a {
  color: #fff;
}

li:hover {
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  min-width: 5rem;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover>ul,
ul li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
  clear: both;
  min-width: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```